# Slow query on view when using single column order by clause

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by

I have a view that joins 24 tables (all but 1 are left outer joins) and 83 columns.  When I Select * from the view without an order by clause it returns 27k rows all columns in about 4:27 seconds.  If I do the same select but add a 'order by requestId' clause it takes 83 minutes to complete.
The column being ordered by is indexed in the original table.

I've tried wrapping it in a Select * from (.......) order by requestId but get the same results.

Suggestions on where to look

Comment: Does this specific query really need columns from all 24 tables? Perhaps you should consider writing a targeted query against the base tables instead of inheriting all the noise from the uber-view.

Comment: Unfortunately yes it does, the data that is returned is exported to excel for further analysis.

Comment: Well I'd ask to see the execution plans but I'm afraid they will give me nightmares. :-(

Comment: What happens if you run the query directly, with ORDER BY and without using a View?

Comment: I was just informed that the many of the views used to be inner joins but have now been converted to left outer joins.  Before this switch the order by made no difference in timings.  Both ways returned the same number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Explain might tell you more, if you have the time to wade through it, but guessing I'd say it's doing a full sort of all 27,000 rows as it can't find a useful ordered index to avoid the extra sort.

It will be hard to spot amongst what you have but a simple scenario would be

TableA KeyColumn,DataColumn, where key column is the primary key

`Select * From TableA Order By KeyColumn`, will use the PK index which is in order, so no sort required.

`select * From TableA Order By DataColumn`, will read the table and then do a sort.

Add an Index for Datacolumn, and the sort won't be required.

As soon as you get to more complex scenarios, it might be that you have a useful index for ordering, but it's not the best for joining, so it does the join fast, and then spends all the time ordering.

If I was looking at this and what to do didn't leap out at me eg. no index at all for requestid, then I'd start chopping tables out of the query until I stopped getting the undesirable behaviour. Then put one back in to get it back, and then use this hopefully less arduous query and `explain` and see if I could get a usful index in or restate the query to use a more useful index.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have order by on a column, then that column must be part of either:
 - An index of its own where only that column exists
 - Or in an index that has the fields in the WHERE clauses and then the fields in the ORDER BY clause in the exact order.

Best if you show me the query. Then I can brainstorm with you.